# Java string[] partial copying

Tags: java, string

How do I take a `String[]`, and make a copy of that `String[]`, but without the first String?
Example: If i have this...

```
String[] colors = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow"};
```

How would I make a new string that's like the string collection colors, but without red in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(colors, 1, colors.length);
```

Answer (score 8):

Forget about arrays. They aren't a concept for beginners. Your time is better invested learning the Collections API instead.

```
/* Populate your collection. */
Set<String> colors = new LinkedHashSet<>();
colors.add("Red");
colors.add("Orange");
colors.add("Yellow");
...
/* Later, create a copy and modify it. */
Set<String> noRed = new TreeSet<>(colors);
noRed.remove("Red");
/* Alternatively, remove the first element that was inserted. */
List<String> shorter = new ArrayList<>(colors);
shorter.remove(0);
```

---

For inter-operating with array-based legacy APIs, there is a handy method in `Collections`:

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
String[] tmp = colorList.split(", ");
Collections.addAll(colors, tmp);
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `shorter.remove(0)` to remove the first element?

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] colors = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow"};
String[] copy = new String[colors.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(colors, 1, copy, 0, colors.length - 1);
```