# java array declaration

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I get the error shown in the comment when I call my class's constructor
(when I remove the array parts everything goes fine). Is this because of a wrong declaration of the array `seq`?

```
public class FibIt implements SeqIt{
    public int counter;
    public int ptr;
    public int [] seq;

    public FibIt(Fib x)
    {   counter=0;
        ptr=0;
        seq[0]=x.first1;         //gives me an error here saying Exception in 
                                     //thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                                 //at FibIt.<init>(FibIt.java:9)
                                     //at Main.main(Main.java:6)
        seq[1]=x.first2;
        for (int i=2; seq[i-1]<=x.last; i++)
            {seq[i]=seq[i-1]+seq[i-2];}
    }
    @Override
    public int func2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ptr++;
        return seq[ptr-1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to initialize your array, so something like `public int[] seq = new int[10];`

Then replace 10 with whatever size you need.

And I was just about to answer your question when @Jack posted a good solution. `ArrayList<Integer>` is pretty useful if you don't know the size of the array.

Comment: what if i dont know the size [depends on the input]?

Comment: Then you have to wait to initialize it until you know the size or use a different data structure, which for java is the `ArrayList`. Arrays can't be resized dynamically.

Comment: @user1763553 You could initialize it in the constructor instead, or yeah, [just use a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10868132/697449).

Comment: @user1763553 in your example, since you are calculating the fibonacci sequence up to parameter `x.last`, you could initialize it inside: `seq = new int[x.last]`.

Comment: the problem is that this is a sequence so i will never know its size even after putting some elements. i dont know when it will end
so how will the ArrayList method be useful? and how to implement it?
thanks!

Comment: @user1763553 then ArrayList is perfect for you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array. One thing is **declaration**, other thing is **inizialization**.

`int[] seq` declares a variable of name `seq` which is an array of `int`. Then you need to effectively inizialize it by assigning to it a constructor for an array: `new int[dimension]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have only declared the array but not initilized.

```
public int [] seq = new int[anySize];
```