# Pass An Array as Argument Having a Different Start Index

Tags: java

How can I pass arrays in Java where I can indicate a different start index (0th index) for the array argument. In C++, you can pass arrays like this

```
myMethed(myArray + 3); // passing method where begin index is 4th element

...

void myMethod(int* arr) {
    int val = arr[0]; // refers to the 4th element
    int val2 = arr[1]; // 5th element
}
```

How can I do something similar in Java. I tried copying a subset of the array using `Arrays.copyOfRange` but I don't want a separate copy but the same array with a different start index.

Of course I can do this:

```
myMethod(int[] arr, int startIndex) {
    int val = arr[startIndex];
    int val2 = arr[startIndex + 1]; 
}
```

But are there other ways without declaring a separate parameter for start index?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No there isn't any other way. You already have the best option, in case you don't want a duplicate array.

Comment: @Rohitjain is correct. The underlying reason is there is no pointer arithmetic, or even pointers, in java. Thank the deity of your choice.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about your own solution. When you write Java code you should think in Java, not in C++. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the same array with a different start index.

In Java, an array is an object whose size is defined at the point it is initialized. The starting index is always zero and the size is fixed. These two cannot be altered after memory has been allocated. In Java ***same array* means *same object*** and **not a memory space**.

Java doesn't allow you to slice the allocated memory as a new array. So, you will always need to create another array, or explicitly pass the starting index to the method you are calling.

Answer (score 3):

In general, [prefer collections over arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10868132/697449). Your particular need can be solved by using `List`s instead:

```
myMethod(List<Integer> list) {
    int val = list.get(0);
    int val2 = list.get(1); 
}

...

List<Integer> myList = ...;
myMethod(myList.subList(3, myList.size()));
```

From the [`List.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) documentation:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. (If `fromIndex` and `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.) **The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.** The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iterator, move it to the required position and pass it as a method argument.

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
Integer myarr[] = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.asList(myarr).subList(2,  myarr.length).toArray(new Integer[2])));
```

Comment: @RueLeonheart It does copy the array.

Comment: why not ?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29

Comment: Here's the source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29 `toArray` always makes a copy - not sure what you meant by pointing to that javadoc (of the wrong `ArrayList`).